# admin.autodiscover() throwing TypeError in urls.py class

Tags: python, django

I'm running into a strange error that I don't know how to fix. I recently upgraded my Ubuntu to 14.04 (which apparently upgraded my Python as well) and Django started throwing a TypeError when I have the **admin.autodiscover()** method uncommented in my urls.py file. When I do comment it, the site works fine, however, I lose my admin access to edit anything from the admin interface. Traceback and requirements below. Thanks!

### Traceback

```
    File "/home/bram/.virtualenvs/viso_project/local/lib/python2.7/site- packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
    99.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
    File "/home/bram/.virtualenvs/viso_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
    337.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
    File "/home/bram/.virtualenvs/viso_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
    365.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
    File "/home/bram/.virtualenvs/viso_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
    360.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
    File "/home/bram/.virtualenvs/viso_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
    40.         __import__(name)
    File "/home/bram/Code/Dropbox/viso_project/viso_project/urls.py" in <module>
    7. admin.autodiscover() 
    File "/home/bram/.virtualenvs/viso_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py" in autodiscover
    29.             import_module('%s.admin' % app)
    File "/home/bram/.virtualenvs/viso_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
    40.         __import__(name)
    File "/home/bram/Code/Dropbox/viso_project/sa_programs/admin.py" in <module>
    55. admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)
    File "/home/bram/.virtualenvs/viso_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in register
    92.                     admin_class.validate(model)
    File "/home/bram/.virtualenvs/viso_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in validate
    106.         validator.validate(cls, model)
    File "/home/bram/.virtualenvs/viso_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/validation.py" in validate
    25.                 getattr(self, m)(cls, model)
    File "/home/bram/.virtualenvs/viso_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/validation.py" in validate_inlines
    224.                 if not issubclass(inline.model, models.Model):
```

### Requirements

```
 Django==1.6.5
    Fabric==1.9.0
    South==1.0
    argparse==1.2.1
    distribute==0.6.24
    django-appconf==0.6
    django-bootstrap-form==3.1
    django-crispy-forms==1.4.0
    django-forms-bootstrap==3.0.0
    django-user-accounts==1.0c9
    ecdsa==0.11
    paramiko==1.14.0
    pinax-theme-bootstrap==5.4.0
    pinax-theme-bootstrap-account==1.0b2
    pycrypto==2.6.1
    pytz==2014.4
    six==1.7.3
    wsgiref==0.1.2
```

> Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/ 
>   Exception Value: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class

Comment: post your admin.py code, please

Comment: Could you post your admin.py file and models.py file, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the upgrade of your Ubuntu (maybe from 12.04 to 14.04) as you saw there is a difference in python versions. This means that your virtual environments which try to use old one has broken. You need to recreate all of your virtual environments, because some strange conflicts may happens even in the standard python libraries.

EDIT:

If you use virtualenvwrapper you can type:

```
rmvirtualenv <envname>
mkvirtualenv <envname> -r <path/to/requirement.txt>
```

This will remove and create environment again with packages listed in your `requirements.txt` file.

NOTE: If you are in active environment first deactivate it before removing virtual environemnt.

Comment: When I upgraded, I ran the command from [this guy's article](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2012/05/30/fixing-virtualenv-after-upgrading-your-distributionpython/), but I used the virtualenvwrapper version (really similar, can't remember it off the top of my head). It did throw an error as it ran, but most of my problems went away. Is there a different way to "reset" an existing environment? Thanks again.

Comment: admin.autodiscover() is still throwing a TypeError :(.

Comment: Re-ran it again after restarting my laptop though and it worked! Thank you so much!